# How to make a one - to - one chat application in php mysql

Tags: chat

ok so my question is that I know how to make a group chat and have one made but I was wondering how to make a one to one i.e. a private chat conversations using php mysqli.
so it doesnt need to be public just for example like facebook chat ( I am just talking about the concept here).
So bascially i want to make a one - to -one chat application in php
please guide me on how to make it

Comment: How do you make it for a group ?

Comment: You know what the difference between a "group chat" and a "one-to-one chat" is? Limiting the one-to-one to 2 people. That's all.

Answer (score 4):

Conceptually, you want to restrict the chats to two people, but also, I'm sure you want to be able to have multiple chats going simultaneously.

**Step 1: Users:**
Assuming you are only letting registered users chat on your website, you need a users table to store user information.

**Step 2: Sessions:**
Next, you want *sessions* or *rooms* where the users chat. Another MySQL table.

**Step 3: User Sessions:**
Now, add another table that links the `users` and `sessions` tables via foreign keys.

**Step 4: User Chats:**
This table contains the actual chats. This needs a foreign key to associate with the session as well as a row in the `user_session`s table, i.e. link to the sending user.

**Step 5: PHP Script:** You will need several scripts for this (probably). First, you need the login the user, then you need to have a list of users where the user can click to start a new chat. When they start a new chat, you need to create a new row in the `sessions` table and associate the two users using the `user_sessions` table.In the actual chat script, you'll want to use Ajax to send chats and update.

That's it, conceptually anyways. Hopefully I've explained it in enough detail that you have a head start on building your chat system. Good luck!